# Ubuntu will not run after installation

Tags: 12.10

I just installed installed Ubuntu on my HP Pavillon dm4 running a Windows 7, and when I choose Ubuntu from the startup option when the company is coming on, it freezes and I cannot do anything else.

Comment: What do you see when it freezes? Or is the GRUB menu itself, where you select Ubuntu, freezing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open one of the console, by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and after providing your credentials, try to write down startx, and look if it will give some errors